# What's the difference among melodic techno, deep house, and progressive house?

Tags: house, techno

I have been listening to melodic techno music lately and I have been enjoying it a lot. However, when I listen to progressive house, I don't feel like I like it a lot. Deep house is in the middle. Some melodic techno musicians that I enjoy listening to are: Worakls and N'to specifically. This song for example (Avoure - Aura) I don't know the genre of it. I don't know if it's melodic techno or house or maybe something else. I would really appreciate it if somebody can explain the differences among melodic techno, deep house, and progressive house with examples, and if somebody can tell me the genre of (Avoure - Aura) song.

Comment: Could you post a link to a recording of the song in question?

Comment: @Aaron:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lLVCRmdmMg&ab_channel=Lane8

Comment: Stop trying to put labels and just enjoy the art! I am PASSIONATE about ALL genres of electronic and Avoure-"Aura" is kinda haunting isn't it? I love this song. I really LOVE LANE 8, and King And Early-"Moving Forward" kinda similar feel.